# Logging to database in ASP.NET Core MVC 6

Tags: database, logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my old MVC5 project all log informations was saved on a sql server database through log4net. I would like keep logger structure of ASP.NET 5 without using any more the log4net. Is it possibile saving the logs on a database table? What kind of code should I use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can implement `ILoggerFactory` and `ILogger` however you like including, for example, logging to a database.

[Here's an example](https://github.com/staff0rd/entityframework-logging/tree/master/src/Atquin.EntityFramework.Logging) of an `ILogger` implementation that uses EntityFramework 6 to save logs to a database.

Comment: Dude! And no license! High five.

Comment: @JimYarbro I see most people prefer a license than not - how does none benefit you?

Comment: I actually prefer a license as well, if only so I know what your preferences are. When I see no license, I assume the fundamentals of the MIT license and I just leave attribution files in my solutions when I use other people's code.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to explain my high five. Basically I was just congratulating you on sharing your code without an overly restrictive license. You recognized your code for what it was, a proof of concept or common approach to a problem, and then didn't overly license it.

Comment: Just a warning, having no licence is actually more restrictive as it implies standard copyright applies. Github is a little different, but I suggest you read their FAQ - https://help.github.com/articles/open-source-licensing/

Comment: As Nick said above, if there is no license the default copyright laws will apply meaning that you can't use the code in your own project. So you are NOT allowed to use the code in the example unless explicitly getting an approval from @Stafford Williams.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification guys, I've added an MIT license to the repo.

Answer (score 2):

I've created new project that is a bit more flexible and available for Entity Framework Core. Here is the GitHub  project site:

https://github.com/msmolka/ZNetCS.AspNetCore.Logging.EntityFrameworkCore