# How to switch between ASP.NET 4.5 and ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, dnx50

I want to implement logger (say log4net) into ASP.Net 5 and MVC 6 Web application, right now log4net doesn't supported for DNX core, therefore I want it to implement in DNX 4.5 (full .net framework) and later on switch into DNX core when log4net is available for DNX core.
Does it feasible ? or is there any other option to implement logger which have file and database logging and should also has DNX 5.0 core support.

Comment: Change the title to use proper terms. DNX is not a suitable name for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Serilog](http://serilog.net) framework. It uses semantic logging and have many adapters (sinks). It also got pre-release version with dnxCore support

Comment: But Serilog does not has sink for database, I need both file and database to store logs.

Comment: I saw that and found Serilog has sql server support but it only for full framework which dnx 4.5 not for DNX Core.
If you know about this plz let me know.. Thanks

Comment: You are right currently you can use it with seq. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/34379650/2483016

Comment: Sinks are also very (very!) easy to write - using `WriteTo.Sink()` and an implementation of `ILogEventSink` might be a workaround while SQL Server support is ported to *Core.

Comment: now you have also serilog sql sink for .net core [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver)